# How to call cs function on click of hyperlink

Tags: asp.net

In my cs file inside the gridview's rowbound event, I have created one hyperlink.

`Hyperlink hy = new Hyperlink()`

If particular condition is true,I have added hyperlink to one column in grid, 
like

`e.Row.cell[2].Controls.add(hy)`

It is working fine. I want to call cs file function from `onclick` event of hyperlink not from javascript.

```
hy.Attributes.Add("onclick","return display()")
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by "CS" you mean "C#" and not "JS".

You're confusing client-side script with server-side actions.

It looks like you're using WebForms - which isn't the kindest to beginners as it artifically conflates the stateless web with "forms" with events and controls.

ASP.NET Server code is executed in response to an incoming HTTP request (generally speaking, either a GET or a POST). A GET request is typically that from a hyperlink or a user typing in an address, for example; whereas POSTs are invariably from `<form>` submissions.

You need to set up your project so your C# code will be called in response to a certain request - in WebForms this isn't easy as by default requests are mapped to `*.aspx` files. The simplist thing for you to do is implement `IHttpHandler` which is when your code is called directly to handle an incoming request.

I suggest you read this article, which should help you to be able to solve your problem by yourself: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335968/Implementing-HTTPHandler-and-HTTPModule-in-ASP-NET

I also suggest avoiding WebForms and moving directly to ASP.NET MVC.